# Laravel Login with www. and without

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5.4

I have a Laravel 5.4 App I created on a Ubuntu 14.04 with NGINX and it runs fine on  https://MyDomain.TLD and  https://www.MyDomain.TLD

The problem is: When I log in either(with or without www), it works fine but cookie informations are not shared to the other variant.

I did not have an issue with this in previous versions of Laravel 5+ .

Any pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to handle www because session is saving based on domain, so try adding below code into `.htaccess` file, one is for force redirection to www and one is to remove www.

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```