# Force to www. with htaccess if the url-router is index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I can't make this working. I tried many ways but no solving this.
I have a .htaccess with routes all request to index.php. On the server is a SSL Cert that works only with www.domain.com, if you using the Internet Explorer and you type teh domain without www. so calls an SSL cert error.

This is why i need to force all requests to www.domain.com instead of domain.com

Now i have in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+) /index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Do any have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158260/3584881)

Comment: Here is the solution.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)