# Laravel Treating www and non www different

Tags: laravel, ssl, vhosts

I have windows server and have domain of godaddy. I took SSL from godaddy and apply on my server. My domain gets secure by SSL but problem come when, i redirect from https://www.example.com and logged in it shows dashboard but when i change url to https://example.com it redirect me to login page.

Here is my VHOST file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/mcpluat/xampp/htdocs/project/public"
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/ [R,L]

<Directory "C:/mcpluat/xampp/htdocs/project/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.HTACCESS file

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Everything is working perfectly but why it is treating www.example.com and example.com a different domain

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158080/laravel-login-with-www-and-without)

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: Because your session cookie is not shared between sub-domains. It's better to use one of these, not both.